# Error de Conexion a base de datos SQL Server

Tags: php, html, sql-server, formularios, validación

Si yo otra vez. Aquí con otra duda. Ya había hecho una pregunta con respecto a la conexión entre SQL Server y PHP. Ahora debo hacer una conexión para la validación de datos en un formulario Login. Necesito que la pagina tome los datos que el usuario ingreso y los compare con los que estan en la base de datos SQL Server, si coinciden entra a otra pagina, si no, que muestre un mensaje de error. Cuando ejecuto todo en el localhost de xampp solo sale una pantalla en blanco y en el link de la pagina esta es el archivo PHP.

Aquí esta mi código HTML de la pagina que estoy desarrollando con el formulario incluido:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ventanaReportes.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="VentanaReportes.js"></script>
    <title>¡Unete al parche! - Reportes Administrador</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header id="principal1">
        <span id="tituloAdmin">
            <h3>Ventana Reportes Administrador - ¡Unete al parche!</h3>
        </span>
    </header>
    <br>
    <div id="box">
        <img src="https://unetealparche.fusagasugadigital.gov.co/Images/UneteAlParche3.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        <br></br>
        <aside id="columna">
            <a href="https://unetealparche.fusagasugadigital.gov.co/Default", id="link" class="button">P&aacute;gina principal</a>
        </aside>
        <aside id="columna1">
            <a href="file:///C:/Users/jdmorales/Documents/3%20-%20Plataforma%20Unete%20al%20parche/Ventana%20reportes/VentanaReportes.html", id="link" class="button">Home</a>
        </aside>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="box1">
        <textarea name="mensaje" rows="6" id="texto" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled">Esta ventana es exclusiva para los administradores de la plataforma, tenga en cuenta que los administradores tienen m&aacute;s privilegios que los usuarios regulares.Para garantizar una mejor funcionalidad de protecci&oacute;n a la privacidad y evitar inconvenientes entre los administradores y los usuarios le pediremos que se registre para poder acceder y verificar su rol como administrador. Si usted es usuario regular el ingreso sera fallido.

Si usted es administrador por favor digite la informaci&oacute;n solicitada en el siguiente formulario:
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <img src="C:/Users/jdmorales/Pictures/user_icon.png" alt="ImagenAdministrador" id="img">
        <form name="LoginAdmin" method="post" action="validar.php" class="login" id="formulario" onsubmit="return validacion()">
            <label><b>Nombre Administrador*: </b><br></label>
            <input type="text" id="AdminName" name="AdminName" placeholder="&#128272;Ingrese su nombre">
            <br><br>
            <label><b>Contrase&ntilde;a*: </b><br></label>
            <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" placeholder="&#128272;ej: 1234**">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" name="EnviarFormularioAdmin" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<hr>
<footer>
    <div  id="footer" style="left: 10px; bottom: 5px;">
        <p>&copy; 2019 - Alcald&iacute;a de Fusagasug&aacute;</p>   
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Y aqui esta mi codigo PHP que se encarga de la validacion del formulario Login

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

    if(isset($_POST['EnviarFormularioAdmin'])){
        //conectar a la base de datos
        $server = "AFTIC004";
        $base = array("Database"=>"UneteAlParche_BD", "UID"=> "codestack", "PWD"=>"jrdLpWad5ik3rFWatjLQ");
        try {
            $conexion = new PDO($server, $base);
            echo "Conexion exitosa";
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Fallo la conexión" . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $administrador=($_POST['AdminName']);
        $contraseña=md5($_POST['contrasena']);
        //establecer la consulta
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM sisAdministrador WHERE IdAdmin = 1, Nombre = '$administrador' AND Password = '$contraseña' AND IdRol = 3";
        $resultado= sqlsrv_query ($conexion, $consulta);

        if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
            if($row['Password'] == $contraseña){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['Nombre'] = $administrador;
                echo "Datos correctos";
                header("Location:https://localhost/Ventana%20/VentanaReportesAdminIngresado.php");
            }else{
                echo "Hubo algun error en los datos ingresados";
                header("Location:validar.php");
                exit();
            }
        }else{
            echo "Ocurrio algun error";
            exit();
        }
    }   
?>
```

Me seria muy útil si me explican paso a paso lo que debo hacer para resolver este problema y pues, obviamente, para aprender. Les agradecería su colaboración y comprensión

Answer (score -2):

Es bastante dificil de leer tu código, te recomendaria que:

- Aprendas php orientado a objetos
- Patron de diseño MVC (Modelo, Vista, Controlador)

Te va ayudar mucho dominar lo antes mencionado, hay muchos videotutoriales para aprender en youtube.

Aca te sugiero uno que me gusto mucho:
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvq-jIkSeTUZEHvKw7Gx3g5CjlcvA3jr1)

Comment: Responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: y te doy el -1  por que  tu aporte en realidad no responde a la pregunta planteada

Comment: Aprendiz, no le puedo hacer un curso de todo eso en un simple comentario, por eso recomende una serie de video para que pueda aprender con 40 horas de video. Saludos

Comment: Se te agradece la intención de ayudar, pero la pregunta no pide aprender sobre POO o MVC además que la zona de respuestas no es espacio para hacer recomendaciones, lee [answer]

Comment: Creeme que me gustaria, en serio, pero no tengo tiempo y necesito resolver este problema, pido ayuda. Pero no de esta forma, soy novato lo reconozco, pero no tienes porque recordarmelo Doormut